# I can't stop Interval in if statement (discord VoiceState)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I can't stop interval declared above the if statement.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const mysql = require('mysql2')

        const con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'nodemysql'
        })

module.exports = client =>{ 

    client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {

        const user = newVoiceState

        var intCoin = setInterval(() =>{
            con.query(`UPDATE coins SET coins = coins + 5 WHERE userid = '${user.id}'`)
            console.log('added coins')
        }, 3000)

        function stopcoins(){
            clearInterval(intCoin)
        }

    if(newVoiceState.channel){
        console.log('joined vc')
        if(!newVoiceState.selfMute){
            console.log('notmuted')
            con.query(`SELECT * FROM coins WHERE userid = '${user.id}'`, (err, rows) =>{
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                if(rows.length <1){
                    con.query(`INSERT INTO coins (userid, coins) VALUES ('${user.id}', 0)`)
                    console.log(`added member: ${user.member.user.username}`)  
                } else {
                    intCoin
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        stopcoins()
        console.log('stop')
    }
    })
}
```

I tried everything I found. Functions, clearing interval and also changing var to null (in funtion I declared that var is changing into con.query etc.)

***EDIT.1***
It's my output in console after joining the VC and after some seconds leaving it

```
joined vc
notmuted
added coins
added coins
added coins
added coins
stop
added coins
added coins
```

Comment: What is the `else { intCoin }` supposed to do? _(it does not do anything)_. The only place where you clear it is in the outer `else`. Do you see the `"stop"` you log? Otherwise, maybe `newVoiceState.channel` is always truthy, and you never fall into the `else`?

Comment: @blex - `else { intCoint }` will log `intCoin` sometimes, depending where it is run from. Maybe that's what the OP was trying to do there

Comment: @marsnebulasoup How could it log anything? It's a variable name containing a Number (the ID of the interval). It's not returned, not logged, not used at all here

Comment: @blex - See this repl: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/CornyInterestingModes#index.js

Comment: @marsnebulasoup You just [blew my mind](https://giphy.com/gifs/lEVZJzy4w15qE). I've been working with JS for 8 years, never seen that

Comment: @blex else is there i guess to insert coins into mysql database if this userid already exists in db.

Comment: @Jentol - Just a thought, but the `voiceStateUpdate` might be called additionally *when you leave the VC*, since that's an update to it's state. So your code works fine, but maybe is just called again when you leave the VC?